# Error when running jekyll new command

Tags: jekyll

when trying to run the following command I receive an error:

```
jekyll new myblog
```

And the error is as follows:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in `require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/filters.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:43
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/jekyll:7
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
```

I run ElementaryOS, and have ruby-dev (1.9.1) also installed.

Comment: This did the trick for me: `gem install json`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same problem and as commented above I installed the json gem with

```
sudo gem install json
```

to fix the problem.

My platform is Ubuntu Precise

Comment: Confirmed for OSX 10.8 as well...seems odd that 'gem install' missed this dependency. Oh well!