# Cannot run Jekyll on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, jekyll

I encountered this issue:

```
gabriele @ osiris { ~ } [ ven nov 15 ] [ 12:57 ]
> jekyll

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline/system_extensions.rb:210: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/gabriele in PATH, mode 040777
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in `require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/filters.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:43
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.3.0/bin/jekyll:7
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
```

after I've installed jekyll on Ubuntu 12.04 with

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev && sudo gem install jekyll
```

This is my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/gabriele/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I also have this problem, i have updated all my gems and made sure that gem json is installed,  but cannot figure out how to get past this...

Comment: @defmeta parkr's solution fixed perfectly the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when running jekyll new command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788258/error-when-running-jekyll-new-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `gem install json` should fix the `LoadError`.

Commander throws that `program version required` error whenever there is a problem loading in the executable (in this case, `bin/jekyll`). As 1.8.7 can't load an internal `json` library (introduced in 1.9), you'll need to install the gem.